# scrape website with hidden csrf token at login with R

Tags: r, rcurl

As part of a late night project I am working on out of interest, I am trying to scrape my Uber trip data off of their website.

I have had a look at the code of the login page on

> https://login.uber.com/login

and have seen that they use POST method in their form setup as follows:

```
<form method="post" class="form" novalidate="">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="1452201446-01-hujzoBTxkYPrJessd6zQwnD2ZOFxMOVgIYN8iXntr6c=">
<input type="hidden" data-js="access-token" name="access_token">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn--full btn--facebook" data-js="facebook-connect">
      <span class="push--ends flush">Continue with Facebook</span>
  </a>
  <p class="primary-font primary-font--semibold text-uber-white background-line push--top push--bottom">
    <span>or use email</span>
  </p>

<div class="form-group push-tiny--top flush--bottom">
  <input type="email" name="email" class="text-input square--bottom " placeholder="Email Address" value="" id="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group push--bottom">
  <input type="password" name="password" class="text-input square--top " placeholder="Password" id="password">
</div>
```

What I have read up is that one needs to send csrf token along when trying to scrape

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

URL_str<-"https://login.uber.com/login"
URL_str2<-"https://riders.uber.com/trips"

email<-"exampleMail@gmail.com"
pass<-"thisisalong"
token<- "1452201446-01-hujzoBTxkYPrJessd6zQwnD2ZOFxMOVgIYN8iXntr6c="

params <- list('email' = email,
               'password' = pass,
               '_csrf_token'=token)

URL_doc = postForm(URL_str2, style="POST",
                   .params=params)
```

If I now try and scrape the site, I get

```
ERROR: FORBIDDEN
```

I have seen some examples in python with similar websites. Can the same be done in R?

Comment: Have you tried rvest? Using the html session stuff should handle this for you

Comment: @hadley Thank you so much for your response! I am using `rvest` at the moment and it seems to be creating the session. I did encounter an error when trying to submit that said `Error: not compatible with STRSXP`, but this was easily fixed with `form$url<-"" `, which had a **null** value. Unfortunately, they have protected the site against scraping as I am receiving a `client error: (403) Forbidden` message when submitting the form. Despite this, I have at least learned how to work with these tokens. Thank you again

Comment: Thank You, I eventually got his to work. 'rvest' does a great job in assisting.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the final solution? Or even better answer it yourself? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer ended up being quite simple:

```
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

session <-html_session("https://login.uber.com/login")

email<-"exampleMail@gmail.com"
pass<-"thisisalong"

#Handling the html_form
form<-html_form(session)[[1]]
form<-set_values(form, email=email, password=pass)

#Found that unless I explicitly assigned the value to empty it created errors
form$url<-""

session_open<-submit_form(session,form)

session_open<-jump_to(session_open,URL_str2)
```

From here on in its straight forward pulling tables using `html_table` and isolating nodes using `html_nodes`. Hope this helps

Comment: I'm getting an error here: `Error in html_form(session) : object 'session' not found`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The session variable was incorrectly named, try again. Should work now