# R - Form input email and password have brackets in field names

Tags: r, authentication, rvest

I have modified the answer from [scrape website with hidden csrf token at login with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665576/scrape-website-with-hidden-csrf-token-at-login-with-r) to fit my needs.

I am working on an R package that will automate the process of logging into the UNICEF MICS survey data sets for registered users. I am having trouble with the input form accepting my username and password. Please see the code and the error message below.

```
library("rvest")
library("RCurl")
library("XML")

my.base.uri <- "https://mics.unicef.org"
my.uri <- paste0(my.base.uri, "/visitors/sign-in")

session <- html_session(my.uri)

email <- ""
pass <- ""

# Handling the html_form
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
form <- set_values(form, email = email, password = pass)
form2 <- set_values(form, visitor.email = email, visitor.password = pass)

# The same error message applies to both attempts using form and form2
# Error: Unknown field names: email, password

<form> 'new_visitor' (POST /visitors/sign-in)
  <input hidden> 'utf8': ✓
  <input hidden> 'authenticity_token': czKvZKYPQnx6CuJR1/R+g904zI3IDGskP1griNl8MIE=
  <input email> 'visitor[email]':
  <input password> 'visitor[password]':
  <textarea> 'g-recaptcha-response' [0 char]
  <input submit> 'commit': Log in
```

As the form field has brackets, what is the best way to specify the form field with the intended input.

I will create another question for help to login to the system with regards to solving the Google ReCaptcha.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are unusual characters in the field name, just wrap the name in quotes.

```
form <- set_values(form, "visitor[email]" = email, "visitor[password]" = pass)
```